# Subtraction in the Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create an excel template for warehouse. In this template are integrated warehouse, sellings and invoices.

I already wrote a code that  transfers data to sellings every time I create an invoice and click a button. I would like to integrate in my code function that can do corrections in my warehouse i.e. when I fill an invoice I put items ID, description, amount and a price. After I click a button I want the items amount in the warehouse sheet to decreased by the same amount as in invoice.

The biggest issue for me was how to write a code that takes information from invoice sheet (ID and items amount), look for exact matches in the warehouse sheet and in the warehouse sheet column "I"(stock) decrease stock with the same amount.

sheet1 - name sheet "warehouse". ID in the column "C"; stock - column "I"; data starts from row "4"
sheet3 - name sheet "invoice". ID in the merged column "A""B"(column 1); amount that I sell in the merged column "S""T""U" (column 4); data starts from row 15 as you can see in the code below.

My code that transfers data to sellings (sheet2). I need to integrate function into this code without creating another button.

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Dim x As Long
Dim erow As Long

'Calculate starting rows
x = 15
With Worksheets("Sellings")
    erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With Worksheets("Invoice")
    Do While .Cells(x, 1) <> ""

        'The next line copies values to Sheet2
        Worksheets("Sellings").Range("A" & erow & ":Z" & erow).Value = .Range("A" & x & ":Z" & x).Value
        'increment row counters
        x = x + 1
        erow = erow + 1
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need VBA at all for this. Sounds like a job for a couple simple worksheet formulas and the COUNTIF function.

Comment: It's not good for me i think, because I use sheet 3 (invoice) as a form.  Every time I fill it with different items. So ID and other information every time different though use the same rows (because I fill form from the top). And a second one countif function need criteria that to count. For me need find by ID item in the different sheet and automaticaly decrease item's stock  amount ordo this by clicking

Comment: I'd assumed you were storing the invoice line items somewhere - that would be the more standard way of doing it.  Stock would then be deliveries - invoiced. If stock is a calculated value, it makes it much easier to audit and it's more likely to be correct.

Comment: I have a code in my template that save every invoice. This code every time gives name accordind invoice number and save in my PC. To audit I use the code above. This code after click look in the form (invoice sheet)  if where are  filled rows if yes, transfer data to sellings sheet and add a date when the data added.

Comment: the code should in each cycle take items ID from the row (invoice sheet) and  find match in the warehouse sheet, then the item is found  the code should decrease stock amount that we can find in the same row as item's ID and the cycle begins again till  row will be empty.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm new in VBA coding. I know how logicaly should look, butthis code for me presently is difficult.